# Rails: Using input from dropdown menu without posting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I'm pretty new to Rails and web dev in general. I need to display two dropdown menus, states and schools, such that schools is only displayed after the user has chosen the state, and schools should only display the schools in the chosen state. What I don't know is how I can use the states choice to decide dynamically what schools to display, without the user having to click Submit. I understand that I may need to use JavaScript, but not knowing JS well, I'm not really sure how to do that. Hope I'm making sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [a simple example](http://phrogz.net/tmp/selpopulate.html) of dynamically populating a select based on data structures already in your JavaScript. If you need to perform a server request after the user selects a state and return the list of schools, you'll need different code (and helpfully a library like jQuery).

Comment: The behavior is exactly what I want, but your variables are declared in JS. I'd like to populate the dropdowns with @states and @schools arrays defined in Ruby (in the controller to be exact). Any hints?

Comment: Your controller sets up your data. Your views take the data and create content to send to the web browser. JavaScript, HTML, and CSS are all content that the browser understands. Some options: a) In your page view emit an HTML `<script type="text/javascript">` tag with your instance variables creating the correct JavaScript text. b) Have a static JS file that performs an AJAX fetch when the state changes, and a controller/action that handles this request and turns the Ruby values for that state into a JSON string response.

Comment: Option a: still not sure how to make JS understand a Ruby array - care to explain? I'm really new :(

Comment: @Anita What template language are you using for your views? (Haml, Erb, something else?)

Comment: .rhtml. This is Rails 1 (can't upgrade b/c of compatibility issues).

Comment: OK, .rhtml is ERb. Depending on your data structures you could do, in your view: `<script type="text/javascript">var states = {<%= @states.map{ |name| "#{name.inspect} : [#{schools.select{ |school| school.state==name }.map{ |sc| "{value:#{sc.id},text:#{sc.name.inspect}}" }.join(",")}]" }.join(',') %>};</script>` Your actual code will vary greatly based on your data structures. General course of action: 1. convert Ruby variables into a single string that is valid JavaScript 2. stick that JS into your view.

Comment: OK, I'm probably asking for too much handholding, but I still don't see how to pick up the state choice _from the dropdown menu_ and use it. The state is an attribute of @user.role where @user is an instance of User. My understanding is I'll make the dropdown with `collection_select("@user.role", "state", @states)` but then what? Since the user hasn't submitted, @user.role.state hasn't been changed, so how can I immediately use their state choice?

Comment: @Anita The code I supplied in my initial answer shows how to do that. I fear that the amount of help you need on this subject is in the form of several tutorials and learning, more than the 500 characters of replies really allow. You may want to try a mailing list or the `##javascript` (irc://irc.freenode.net/##javascript) and `#rubyonrails` (irc://irc.freenode.net/#rubyonrails) IRC channels for personal, in-depth support on learning the technologies involved.

Comment: Yep, I'm quite underqualified, but I was hoping there'd be a way to do this that doesn't require knowing more than HTML and Rails, because it seems like such a simple task. Anyhow, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do this with AJAX. I'm not going to customize this for Rails 1 but you should be able to follow the idea. Your first dropdown has a list of states, and each state has a list of schools.

```
// some js file that's loaded from your layout
// When your states dropdown is changed it fires an ajax call
var success = function(response) {
  for (var school in response.schools) {
    $('#schools_dropdown').html('');
    var option = $(document.createElement('option')).html(school.name).val(school.id);
    option.appendTo($('#schools_dropdown'));
  }
});

$('#states_dropdown').change(function() {
  $.get('/state/' + $(this).val() + '/schools', success);
});

# your schools controller
def index
  @schools = State.find(params[:id]).schools
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :json => @schools }
  end
end
```

So maybe you don't have jQuery and maybe rendering json is different in Rails 1... but the idea is the same. You have some javascript attached to your states dropdown so that when it changes, you pull off the id of that state and make an AJAX call to your controller. The last parameter to that AJAX call is a success function that loops through all the schools sent back by the controller, clears the schools dropdown, and adds options into the dropdown one by one.